Why does useState() run in an endless loop if the argument is an object or array?
I'm using the useState() hook in Deno Fresh, which is based on Preact. In an island I have:
import { useState } from "preact/hooks";

export default function(){
  const [state, setState] = useState('hi')
  const str = 'a'
  setState(str)
  console.log(state)
} 

This works fine. But if I use an object instead:
- const str = 'a'
- setState(str)
+ const obj = {a: 'a'} 
+ setState(obj)

Then it's trapped in an endless loop. Why is that?

Because strings are compared by value and objects by reference - that's a new object every time.

I suggest reading the caveats in the documentation. An unconditional state setter call in a component function is always a bad idea, whether with a string or something else, and it isn't always guaranteed React won't call the component function again as a result, even when you call it with the same value, though it usually won't.

This boils down to the question:


console.log("a" === "a");
console.log({ x : "a" }  === { x : "a"}); //Why is this false when above is true



Preact or React or JS uses object references to compare objects. Hence, two objects will never be equal.
React will not be able to optimize the rendering, even if the objects are technically equal and will keep on rerendering

I guess I need to know how setState() works behind the scene. Do you have any good source that you recommend?

https://react.dev/reference/react/useState

For Preact, this is the actual implementation, newArg !== oldArg. As simple of a check as it gets.
